# BeautifulSoup not finding all tables in xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup

New to python/scraping. Trying to obtain the info for this xml (https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/xml.php?id=BOE-A-2022-2225)

```
<p class="centro_redonda">A) CIGARROS Y CIGARRITOS</p>
<table class="tabla">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="cabeza_tabla"> </th>
<th class="cabeza_tabla">
<p class="cabeza_tabla">PVP</p>
<p class="cabeza_tabla">–</p>
<p class="cabeza_tabla">Euros/Unidad</p>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<colgroup>
<col width="60%"/>
<col width="16%"/>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="cuerpo_tabla_centro" colspan="2">
<em>A. FLORES</em>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cuerpo_tabla_izq">A. Flores Gran Reserva Connecticut Valley Reserve Robusto C (10).</td>
<td class="cuerpo_tabla_coma">12,95</td>
```

Im trying to obtain the td texts but when exporting the info to a excel I only get the first part of the xml ((A) CIGARROS Y CIGARRITOS). The full file has more sections ((B) CIGARS, (C)...).

This is what I got so far

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'tabla'})
columns = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.find_all("th")]
data = []

for tr in table.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    data.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all("td")])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False)
```

I tried with a `find_all()` instead of `find()` for the table but got the `error: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'`. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all tables and avoid the error while using `find_all()` you have to iterate the ResultSet.

```
data = []
for t in soup.find_all('table', {'class':'tabla'}):
    columns = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in t.find_all("th")]

    for tr in t.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
        data.append(dict(zip(columns,[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all("td")])))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  |  | PVP–Euros/Unidad | PVP–Euros/Envase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A. FLORES | nan | nan |
| 1 | A. Flores Gran Reserva Connecticut Valley Reserve Robusto C (10). | 12,95 | nan |
| 2 | AJ. FERNANDEZ | nan | nan |
| 3 | Aj. Fernandez New World Cameroon Selection Gordo C (20). | 9,95 | nan |
| 4 | Aj. Fernandez New World Oscuro Virrey Gordo 6 X 58 C (21). | 8,95 | nan |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 115 | Eternal Smoke Red Lips (50 g). | 2,10 | nan |
| 116 | Eternal Smoke Wild Lit (50 g). | 2,10 | nan |
| 117 | Forever Gold Border (200 g). | 12,00 | nan |
| 118 | Forever Gold Border (50 g). | 3,50 | nan |
| 119 | Forever Gold Border Edición Limitada (50 g). | 3,50 | nan |

Comment: That WORKED!! Thanks man... the only ting that, the '''for tr in table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")''' instead of table.find() was t.find(). Thanks a lot dude!